# How to run a script on image?

Tags: javascript, youtube

This script below slides and rebuilds a div with a Youtube video when I press a button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
  $('#slide_up').click(function(){
    $('#slidingDiv').slideToggle('', function (){
      var obj = $(this);
      if(obj.is(':hidden')){
        obj.html( obj.html() );
      }
    });
  });
});//]]>  

<div style="display: block;" id="slidingDiv">
  <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/r13a2VUTajU" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="315" width="560"></iframe>
</div>

<input value="Slide and rebuild" id="slide_up" type="button">
```

I want to use an image instead of a button.

How should I modify a script to run a slide function after I click on img?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input value="Slide and rebuild" id="slide_up" type="image" src="yourimage.jpg">
```

This should work. Unless I didn't understand the question

Comment: No problem! Please accept the answer if it worked and answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `onclick` attribute

`<img src="your src" onclick="your javascript function" />`

Comment: He already has the jQuery listener on the input `$('#slide_up').click(function()`